# Test class pattern for pricebook when standard pricebook is deactivated

Tags: pricebook, failing-tests, product

I'm trying to write a test class without the "seealldata=true" option and all I have is a custom pricebook, as my standard pricebook has been deactivated.

The relevant part of the test is as follows;

```
@isTest
public class Test1  {
    private static testmethod void Test1a(){

        //Id standardPbId = test.getStandardPricebookId();
        Pricebook2 pbk1 = new Pricebook2 (Name='Standard Price Book 1',Description='Test Pricebook Entry 1', isActive=true);
        insert pbk1;   

        Product2 prd1 = new Product2 (Name='Test Product Entry 1', Family='Best Pricebook ever', isActive = true);
        insert prd1;             

        PricebookEntry pbe1 = new PricebookEntry (Pricebook2ID=pbk1.id,Product2ID=prd1.id,UnitPrice=50.0, isActive=true, UseStandardPrice = false);
        insert pbe1;
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Type = 'Vendor');
        insert acc;

        Opportunity opp1 = new Opportunity (Name='Opp1', AccountId = acc.id);
        insert opp1;
        }        
    }
```

...But the test fails with a "STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED" error.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> To be used in custom price books, all standard prices must be added as
>   price book entries to the standard price book.

So you will still need to define a standard price

```
PricebookEntry sPBE = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = test.getStandardPricebookId(), Product2Id = prd1, UnitPrice = 1000);
insert standardPBE;
```

Additionally, although not related, if StandardPriceBook Is not active and you need to use it simply use:

```
PriceBook2 pb = New PriceBook2(Id = test.getStandardPricebookId(), isActive = true);
update pb;
```

Which will allow you to use the standard price book.